# System.xml.linq vs system.xml.xpath in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, linq-to-xml

Ok so I have referenced a namespace so I don't need to provide that context when working with linq to xml

```
Imports <xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
```

so I can get to a list of nodes in my document by, for example the following query

```
For Each nd In Me.CurrentDocument...<w:pPr>.<w:spacing>
Next
```

But now I have quite a complicated xpath that I want to execute with an or, e.g.

```
"//w:rPr/w:sz|w:szCs[@w:val]"
```

I can reference system.xml.xpath to expose the XPPathSelectElements option but then I have to pass a namespace each time.

```
    For Each nd In Me.CurrentDocument.XPathSelectElements(
     "//w:rPr/w:sz|w:szCs[@w:val]", NameSpaceManager)
        nd.@w:val = "16"
    Next
```

Can't I get this to default? or do I have to set up a namespace manager and use that every time I want to query on an xpath?

Or, should I be able to execute the same query with the xpath or (|) using linq to xml and the vb shorthand notation?

**UPDATE:**

Well the more I work on this, the more I see I can get everything done without using XPath queries.

There's a good article here that goes over a lot of the differences: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675156.aspx

### Xpath OR

```
"//w:rPr/w:sz|w:szCs"
```

becomes

```
Me...<w:rPr>.<w:sz>.Concat(Me...<w:rPr>.<w:szCs>)
```

### XPath Position

Xpath to get all cells in the first row of all tables:

```
"//w:tbl/w:tr[1]/w:tc"
```

becomes

```
Me...<w:tbl>.SelectMany(Function(a) a.<w:tr>.Take(1).<w:tc>)
```

Without SelectMany, you just get the first cell in the first row of the first table:

```
Me...<w:tbl>.<w:tr>.Take(1).<w:tc>
```

So, as it turns out you can do just about everything that XPath can do, you do get some intellisense but I personally think it's not necessarily easier to write than xpath queries, but it may well be easier to maintain and debug.